# How to select most frequent value with condition for multiple columns in netezza?

Tags: sql, netezza

I want to get the most frequent value for each column. If it has the same frequent it will return 'equal'.

I have data like below table and I use netezza.

```
number    cat1     cat2    
      1          a       w
      1          a       w
      1          b       q
      1          c       q
      2          b       w
      2          b       w
      2          b       e
      3          d       w
      3          d       w
      3          e       q
      3          e       q
```

My expected output:

```
number     cat1     cat2    
  1          a     equal
  2          b       w
  3        equal   equal
```

ps. I have about 30 categorical columns in my real data.

Comment: Please elaborate, this question is unclear to me. for instance what does ‘has the same frequent’ mean ?

Comment: For instance number 1 has 2 w (2 rows) in cat2 so, it returns 'equal'.

Comment: Yeah, but number 2 has 2 w as well and it does not return ‘equal’ ???

Comment: Sorry for my unclear answer number 1 has 2 w and 2 q (2 rows) in cat2 so, it returns 'equal'.